# How to grant su access without password to one user only in wheel group (FreeBSD)?

Tags: security, freebsd, pam, pfsense, su

I know how to enable su without a password for all wheel group users by adding the appropriate configuration line in `/etc/pam.d/su`.

I do not want to enable this for all wheel users but only one particular user.

I am using FreeBSD 8.1. How do I do this?

UPDATE in response to comments below

This is a pfSense box. Underlying OS is FreeBSD 8.1 but as usual for pfSense a lot of functionality is missing, notably the entire ports collection. I wish to have one privileged user (in wheel group) able to invoke su - without having to type the root password. Enabling this for all wheel users using PAM is easy. I do not know the correct PAM configuration to allow bypassing the password for one particular user. I am constrained by company policy in how much alteration I can make. This is a running, mission-critical machine and I cannot take the risk of accidentally bringing it down. I have inherited administration of this machine but radical changes to its configuration are not practicable or permissible at this present time. I have PAM; I don't have sudo. I wish I did, but I don't.

Comment: Privilege escalation is always a security breach but as you ask : Configure sudo without password for that particular user?

Comment: This is FreeBSD. I do not have sudo. I want to do this via PAM.

Comment: sudo is available for FreeBSD ports. Update your port tree if you do not have sudo.

Comment: Please include more details of your situation.  What is the user supposed to do?  Why on a FreeBSD system you are unable to use/install sudo.  A little sample senario perhaps of what you are specifically trying to do.

Comment: :: Wonders if compiling sudo on a FreeBSD box and uploading it to the pfsense box would work ::

Comment: FreeBSD packages work just fine on a pfSense box... pfSense didn't meddle with OS much, but the ports tree is not included for space reasons.

Comment: I have to ask why you have multiple wheel users in the first place, and why one has to be able to gain root privileges without a password. This seems exceedingly odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does FreeBSD have user private groups? If not, create a group and put only that user in it. Then in `/etc/pam.d/su` add something like

```
auth            sufficient      pam_group.so            no_warn group=foo
```

where `foo` is the group name.

Comment: This might work. I will experiment and report my findings. It certainly would be useful to have a pam_user module analogous to pam_group. The pfSense distro I am working with does not have pam_listfile, which might otherwise have been an option

Comment: OK, thanks very much Mark, this worked perfectly. I created a new group `nopw` and added the privileged user to it. Expanded answer below

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `sudo` to do this. It's easy and a well tested method.

Please reference the sudo man page for more information.

Comment: This is a pfSense box. It does not have sudo. It does not have ports. It does not even have portsnap. It does, however, have PAM, which is why I want to use PAM and not sudo and not ports.

Comment: BTW, for reference, this information should have been included in the original message so we get to your specific problem.  So you are attempting to use an open source router/firewall box to support a user for what capabilities?

Comment: The [FreeBSD 8.1 package for `sudo`](ftp://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/i386/packages-8.1-release/security/sudo-1.7.3.tbz) will install on pfSense.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with just putting just the one user in the wheel group?

Comment: @Chris S. -- See the first line in this question.

Comment: Fair enough. See the second line of the Question for why this Answer is wrong. =P

Comment: They seem to be contradictory statements really.  So put only ONE user in the wheel group which is what I was getting to.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Wagner came up with a solution, for which many thanks. I created a group `nopw` and added the privileged user to it. Then I made a 'sufficient' no_warn rule for that group only using the pam_group.so module. Now the `auth` section of my `/etc/pam.d/su` file looks like:

```
auth   sufficient   pam_rootok.so   no_warn
auth   sufficient   pam_self.so     no_warn
auth   sufficient   pam_group.so    no_warn group=nopw root_only fail_safe
auth   requisite    pam_group.so    no_warn group=wheel root_only fail_safe
auth   include      system
```